# Not understanding why it is not recognising a key input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input

When I press escape, the pause menu in my game should become visible to the user and the game time should freeze. However, the program seems to not recognize the input when I press escape. I have tried using different Keys and they did not work either. I went to make sure that it was the input that was the problem by doing a Debug.Log command and when I tested I was still not getting any signs of it triggering. Here is the code. I hope someone can help me out.

```
public static bool GameIsPaused = true;

public GameObject PauseMenuUI;
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        if (GameIsPaused)
        {
            Resume();
        }
        else
        {
            Pause();
        }
    }
}

void Resume()
{
    PauseMenuUI.SetActive(false);
    Time.timeScale = 1f;
    GameIsPaused = false;
}

void Pause()
{
    PauseMenuUI.SetActive(true);
    Time.timeScale = 0f;
    GameIsPaused = true; 
}
```

Comment: So, Debug.Log inside the if-condition doesnt work? Does Debug.Log inside Update() produce anything, is the script enabled? is the gameobject active?

Comment: ok so i tested that and it was not producing the Logs now what i did find out is if its set to active by default it starts to work. atleast the debug. but i need to keep it unactive until its pressed escape since it is a pause menu. so do i maybe need to reference it on the player for example and trigger it from there?

Comment: Yes, an inactive gameobjects script does not run Update()

Comment: ahhh ok good to know il see if that works then

Comment: yes that worked thank you so much its been bothering me, im kinda new to unity i had no idea that the update void will not run unless the entity is active. thanks for your help

Comment: @FredrikWiderberg consider writing a proper answer for this question, please.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues answer added

Answer (score 1):

As we discussed in the comments, the GameObject which the `PauseMenu`-script is attached to was not active.

An inactive gameobject will have all its components disabled.

> Update is called every frame, if the MonoBehaviour is enabled.
>   https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html

So your update code did not run, hence never detecting when Escape was pressed.